# Mysql nested left joins with counts

Tags: mysql

I have a set of MySQL three tables in a "has many" relationship: deals, orders, and coupons.

```
Deals
|----|--------------|
| id |    title     |
|----|--------------|
|  1 | Some deal    |
|  2 | Another deal |
|----|--------------|

Orders
|----|---------|-----------|
| id | deal_id |   state   |
|----|---------|-----------|
|  1 |       1 | purchased |
|  2 |       1 | purchased |
|  3 |       1 | expired   |
|  4 |       2 | purchased |
|----|---------|-----------|

Coupons
|----|----------|
| id | order_id |
|----|----------|
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        1 |
|  4 |        2 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        4 |
|----|----------|
```

So, deals have many orders, which have many coupons.

What I'd like to do is select on the deals table while counting the number of purchased orders and coupons.

I know how to get a count on paid orders already:

```
SELECT deals.*, count(orders.id) AS orders_purchased_count FROM deals
LEFT JOIN orders ON deals.id=orders.deal_id AND orders.state='purchased'
WHERE deal_id < 3
GROUP BY deals.id

Deals
|----|--------------|------------------------|
| id |    title     | orders_purchased_count |
|----|--------------|------------------------|
|  1 | Some deal    |                      2 |
|  2 | Another deal |                      1 |
|----|--------------|------------------------|
```

Similarly, I can get a count of coupons for orders:

```
SELECT orders.*, count(coupons.id) AS coupons_count FROM orders
LEFT JOIN coupons ON orders.id=couoons.orders_id
WHERE orders.state='purchased'
GROUP BY orders.id

Orders
|----|-----------|---------------|
| id |   state   | coupons_count |
|----|-----------|---------------|
|  1 | purchased |             3 |
|  2 | purchased |             2 |
|  4 | purchased |             1 |
|----|-----------|---------------|
```

My question is: **How do I combine these so that I can add coupons_count next to orders_purchased_count?**

```
Deals
|----|--------------|------------------------|---------------|
| id |    title     | orders_purchased_count | coupons_count |
|----|--------------|------------------------|---------------|
|  1 | Some deal    |                      2 |             5 |
|  2 | Another deal |                      1 |             1 |
|----|--------------|------------------------|---------------|
```

The tricky thing, in my case, will be to run the `WHERE deal_id < 3` filter when selecting from `deals` before I join on `orders` and to run the `WHERE orders.state='purchased'` filter when selecting from `orders` before I join on `coupons`. It's a large dataset and I don't want to load all my `orders` and `coupons` into memory for the purpose of joining.

At a loss for how to do this.

Comment: Is there a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?  I couldn't understand your concerns which part was going to be tricky.

```
SELECT deals.*, COUNT(DISTINCT(orders.id)) AS orders_purchased_count, COUNT(coupons.id) AS coupons_count
FROM deals
LEFT JOIN orders 
  ON deals.id=orders.deal_id
    AND orders.state='purchased' 
LEFT JOIN coupons
  ON orders.id=coupons.orders_id
WHERE deal_id < 3
GROUP BY deals.id;
```

Comment: The "tricky" part he was likely struggling with is getting the orders purchased count correct. Which is why the `distinct` in `count`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af049/26

Comment: Perfect, it yields correct and it runs quickly on my data set. I was worried I'd have to use a subquery on orders/coupons and didn't want to load them all before filtering on deals. Using only joins avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with a co related subquery  and join

```
SELECT deals.*, count(orders.id) AS orders_purchased_count 
(
SELECT  count(id) FROM coupons WHERE orders_id = orders.id 

) AS coupons_count 

FROM deals
LEFT JOIN orders ON deals.id=orders.deal_id AND orders.state='purchased'
WHERE deal_id < 3
GROUP BY deals.id
```